# Custom Exception handling in Python 2.6.5 and importing modules

Tags: python

I had one script with custom exception classes in the form of:

```
class DirectionError(Exception):
    pass
```

I had my functions in the same script in the form of:

```
def func1(x):
    if x == 1:
        raise DirectionError
```

I put my function calls into a try/except/except block in the form of:

```
try:
    func1(2)
except DirectionError:
    logging.debug("Custom error message")
    sys.exit()
except:
    logging.debug(traceback.format_exc())
```

I subsequently moved the functions into a seperate mytools.py file.  I import the mytools.py file into my main python script.

I moved the custom exception classes into the mytools.py file but exception is not reaching the main python script.

How do I get those functions in the mytools.py file to send the exception back to the try/except block in my main python script?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you imported your `mytools.py` into the main python script? Do you get any errors? Try explicitly importing DirectionError: `from mytools import DirectionError`

Comment: Your exception raise only when you call func1(1), and you are calling func1(2).

Comment: @KurzedMetal, Sorry.. I got that.  Let's say func1(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how did you import mytools.
If you imported it as

```
import mytools
```

then changing:

```
except DirectionError:
```

to:

```
except mytools.DirectionError:
```

should work.

If you imported only your function with:

```
from mytools import func1
```

change it to:

```
from mytools import func1, DirectionError
```

Basically, you need to import the DirectionError class into your main code and reference it correctly.

Besides, your exception raise only when you call func1(1), and you are calling func1(2).

Answer (score 0):

Define the exception in its own scriptfile and then import that file into both mytools.py and your main script

Comment: So I say import customExceptions.py and then do try: func1(2) except: customExceptions.DirectionError

Comment: Would you be able to explain why this is necessary? Thank you.

Comment: It isn't necessary to move it into his own file, it is only necessary to import it.